# Single request search in multiples tables using join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got to search in 3 differents tables a term.
Here are my 3 requests, I'd like to make only one.
Tables are teledis, afr, software_cache.
If you want, here is my schema : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlIkp.jpg

```
SELECT teledis.nameid
FROM teledis 
LIKE vulcain = '%XXX%';



SELECT teledis.nameid
FROM joinafr
    JOIN teledis
        ON joinafr.teledis_id = teledis.idteledis
    JOIN afr 
        ON joinafr.afr_id = afr.idafr
WHERE afr.name LIKE '%XXX%';



SELECT teledis.nameid
FROM softs
    JOIN software_cache
        ON softs.id_soft_cache = software_cache.id
    JOIN joinsoft
        ON softs.idsofts = joinsoft.soft_id
    JOIN teledis
        ON joinsoft.soft_id = teledis.idteledis WHERE software_cache.name LIKE '%XXX';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT teledis.nameid
FROM teledis 
WHERE vulcain LIKE '%XXX%'
UNION
SELECT teledis.nameid
FROM joinafr
    JOIN teledis
        ON joinafr.teledis_id = teledis.idteledis
    JOIN afr 
        ON joinafr.afr_id = afr.idafr
WHERE afr.name LIKE '%XXX%'
UNION
SELECT teledis.nameid
FROM softs
    JOIN software_cache
        ON softs.id_soft_cache = software_cache.id
    JOIN joinsoft
        ON softs.idsofts = joinsoft.soft_id
    JOIN teledis
        ON joinsoft.soft_id = teledis.idteledis WHERE software_cache.name LIKE '%XXX';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT teledis.nameid, afr.name, software_cache.name
FROM softs
JOIN software_cache
    ON softs.id_soft_cache = software_cache.id
JOIN joinsoft
    ON softs.idsofts = joinsoft.soft_id
JOIN joinafr
    ON joinafr.teledis_id = teledis.idteledis
JOIN teledis
    ON joinsoft.soft_id = teledis.idteledis
JOIN afr 
    ON joinafr.afr_id = afr.idafr
WHERE afr.name LIKE '%XXX%' OR software_cache.name LIKE '%XXX';
```